# How to get data from a node.js server using a http reqest with SFML in C++?

Tags: c++, node.js, http, server, sfml

So, the code I currently have in C++ is:

```
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // prepare the request
    sf::Http::Request request("/", sf::Http::Request::Get);

    // send the request
    sf::Http http("http://localhost:3000/");
    sf::Http::Response response = http.sendRequest(request);

    // check the status
    std::cout << response.getStatus();

    return 0;
}
```

And I've created a [local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7XRK.jpg) using node.js and I'd like to get the json data.
The code above doesn't work and I don't know what to do. The error code I get is 1001 (ConnectionFailed).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using the `sf::Http` constructor wrong.

The constructor calls [`setHost`](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Network/Http.cpp#L317-L345) which does not parse port numbers. You need to explicitly pass the port number as follows:

```
sf::Http http("http://localhost", 3000);
```

Comment: Holy, I don't know how I missed that. It seems to be working now, thanks very much!